# Android Studio does not recognize Java and Kotlin classes in the same project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I made a Java project in Android Studio, and tried to put a file in Kotlin. But you can see that Android Studio doesn't recognize Kotlin files in the same project that contains Java files. Can anyone help please?

Attached photos explaining better:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDNoV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwWbA.png

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question Good luck 

Comment: Ok, but the objective is to show the code and the error message. Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used Annotation in that class. Add kotlin-kapt plugin in build.gradle/module ,this may fix your problem. You can read this [document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html) for more guidence.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt' 
//    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize' // this instead of kotlin-android-extensions
}
```

Then sync your project.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/ASQ2PQg

Comment: The plugins that you wrote were not found: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/y2iwCQU

Answer (score 0):

I discovered to fix this error.
It has to put the following code in root build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Thank you very to all that tried to help.